# raw SQL to laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

How do you convert this raw sql builder to laravel DB Builder

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `applications` 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   `applicants` 
                      INNER JOIN `applicant_application` 
                              ON `applicants`.`id` = 
                                 `applicant_application`.`applicant_id` 
               WHERE  `applications`.`id` = 
                      `applicant_application`.`application_id` 
                      AND `user_id` = 18) 
ORDER  BY `created_at` DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

This is what I've tried but doesn't seem to work

```
DB::table('applications as apt')
->whereExists( function ($q) {
    $q->from('applicants as app')
    ->join('applicant_application as aa', 'app.id', '=', 'aa.applicant_id')
    ->where('apt.id', '=', 'aa.application_id')
    ->where('app.user_id', '=', 18);
})->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `apt.id` and `aa.application_id` are two columns from diff tables, and you are using `where` to compare the `apt.id` with **string** `'aa.application_id'`.

You need to use `whereColumn` to **compare two different columns**:

```php
->whereColumn('apt.id', '=', 'aa.application_id')
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks :)